# OpenGL: How to optimize 2d rendering with multiple layers overlapping each other in 3d mode?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering, 2d

I know how to speed up rendering in 3d by simply rendering the nearest planes first.

But how do i get advantage of this type of method in 2d mode? I cant use depth testing because they are all in the same z-level.

So i was thinking if it could be speed up when i dont need to render the invisible parts of the layers "below". Is this possible?

Note that i am rendering in 3d mode, there may be 3d objects and 2d objects at the same time. So i cant switch to 2d render only, i always use 3d coordinates for everything. And i may rotate the camera as i wish, so camera-specific tricks arent acceptable.

**Edit:** i tried the method Ville suggested:
[image]

### ( http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/7857/zfighting.png )

but as you see, it will result in z-fighting.

The code i used for rendering that is here:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

glColor4f(1,0,0,1);
DrawQuad(0, 0, 10, 10);

glColor4f(0,0,1,1);
DrawQuad(5, 5, 15, 15);

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Comment: Depth testing (with default mode GL_LESS) will still work even if all your 2d-objects are on the same z-level. Pixels will not be updated twice.

Comment: @Ville, that would result in z-fight. see the image i posted.

Comment: You are right, I thought you meant 2d-objects HUD-style and didn't understand you intended to rotate the camera around the 2d-objects too. For this I would render in ortho-mode to a texture first like derkyjadex suggest.

Comment: @Ville, wouldnt rendering to a texture be overkill...? im specifically trying to find faster than the method i use atm: just disabling depth testing. But i was hoping i could optimize this a bit since it does actually draw some useless pixels that are never visible...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are rendering all your "2D" objects on the same plane. You could render your 2D parts into an off-screen framebuffer with an orthographic projection and give them different Z values as datenwolf suggested. Then render the framebuffer texture into your main 3D scene.

Comment: Or just clear the depth buffer and overdraw with the 2D planes.

Comment: rendering into a framebuffer is faster instead of just disabling depth test?

Comment: Possibly not, datenwolf perhaps has a better suggestion there. But you're not disabling the depth test, you're clearing the depth buffer so that OpenGL "forgets" about the 3D objects already rendered. Using a separate framebuffer effectively does the same, but you get to keep your 3D depth buffer if some of the 3D objects are supposed to appear in front of the 2D ones.

Answer (score 1):

What do you understand by 2D mode? Do you mean orthographic projection? Then I have good news: Depth testing works there perfectly as well. gluOrtho2D is basically the same like glOrtho(..., -1, 1); i.e. you have the Z range -1 ... 1 to spend.

**EDIT due to comment:**

It is perfectly possible to combine rendering several projections in one single frame:

```
void render_perspective_scene(void);

void render_ortho_scene(void);

void render_HUD();

void display()
{
    float const aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;

    glViewport(0,0,win_width,win_height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-aspect*near/lens, aspect*near/lens, -near/lens, near/lens, near, far);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_perspective_scene();

    // just clear the depth buffer, so that everything that's
    // drawn next will overlay the previously rendered scene.
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-aspect*scale, aspect*scale, -scale, scale, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_ortho_scene();

    // Same for the HUD, only that we render
    // that one in pixel coordinates.
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, win_width, 0, win_height, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_HUD();
}
```

Of course if you've fallen for those bad tutorials that place the projection matrix setup in the reshape handler you're of course mind blocked, to see that obvious solution.

Comment: "Note that i am rendering in 3d mode, there may be 3d objects and 2d objects at the same time. So i cant switch to 2d render only" did you read that?

Comment: Of course you can switch that. How do you think game HUDs are rendered?

Comment: HUD is not what im trying to achieve here. Imagine you have normal 3d world, and then you render the 3d world in 2d mode viewed from up, and then you rotate the camera and you see the world flatten.

Comment: Okay, you suffer some serious misconception there: OpenGL is not a scene graph. Once you've sent some geometry to OpenGL is simply rasterizes it to pixels and then forgets about the geometry. So going ortho, render something and then rotateing/switching projection will not alter whatever you've already drawn to the framebuffer. So what you actually need to do is either render to textures, then draw those quads, or do some shader magic to project the geometry flat onto those planes, but still pass depth values usable for depth testing.

Comment: i tried with shaders but it also required depth test off... i guess theres no solution for this then, not that i really need it either, but as a optimization freak i'd like to know every trick :P

Comment: You can use the shader to write depth values that lie out of the 2D plane; of course you'll have to clear the depth buffer before to make this work.

Comment: maybe you could provide example of that kind of shader ?